# Grafana dashboards vs. console templates in Prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus

If I understand correctly, Prometheus supports two ways of creating dashboards with graphs that visualize its time-series data. One way employs Grafana and its dashboards, the other way employs Prometheus' own web frontend and its  [console templates](https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/consoles/).

In comparing those two options, is it correct to assume that the one that employs Grafana is the more recent one, by now receives more attention, and is perhaps the better way to go under common circumstances and looking forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended that new users use Grafana. Console templates are more powerful, but with that also more challenging to use.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience with **Grafana** and **Prometheus** - if You are beginner in topics related to machine data monitoring - I definitely recommend Grafana for creating Your dashboard. Unfortunately, community is not huge and rich of specific answers what You can see on the right part of this webpage (*Related part*).

If You are not sure enough if it is for You - check this [link](https://play.grafana.org/d/000000012/grafana-play-home?orgId=1) and play a little bit with Grafana on sample data.

You have to base on general answers, but even using only them, **Grafana** GUI and **PromQL** (which I use for Prometheus data) are very intuitive and syntax doc on their [website](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/) is far enough to achieve most of typical graphs, counters and stats. Just to mention - if You have already prior experience with **SQL** - You'll find some similarities with logic, but start with **PromQL** syntax can be little bit challenging for start.